# While Adding adding Row dynamically outputpanel rendering incorrectly

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

[image]When I am adding a row dynamically on  a click of a button its getting added outside my table. 
I understand that outputpanel renders as span tag . Do we have any solution to my problem .

SERVICE PART

```
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr class="headerRow">
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    Action
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    Product
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Description</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Qty</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Serial</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Batch</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Action</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Stock Location</span>
                </td>
                 <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Replenish?</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dataRow odd">
                <td class="dataCell" colspan="1">
                    <span><apex:selectList id="Action1" value="{!anyWord}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Consumed" itemLabel="Consumed"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Keep in Trunk" itemLabel="Keep in Trunk"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Return" itemLabel="Return"/>
                    </apex:selectList></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell"  width="20%">
                    <span>1503243</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>LASER</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>1</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>X27353</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>34</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Installed</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Trunk</span>
                </td>
                 <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Yes</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="dataRow odd">
                <td class="dataCell" colspan="1">
                    <span><apex:selectList id="Action2" value="{!anyWord}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Consumed" itemLabel="Consumed"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Keep in Trunk" itemLabel="Keep in Trunk"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Return" itemLabel="Return"/>
                    </apex:selectList></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell"  width="20%">
                    <span>1503223</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>LASER</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>2</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>X27363</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>31</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Not Installed</span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>Warehouse</span>
                </td>
                 <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span>No</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <apex:outputPanel id="addRow" layout="block">
            <apex:repeat value="{!row}" var="con">
            <tr class="dataRow odd">
                <td class="dataCell" colspan="1">
                    <span><apex:selectList value="{!anyWord}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Consumed" itemLabel="Consumed"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Keep in Trunk" itemLabel="Keep in Trunk"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Return" itemLabel="Return"/>
                    </apex:selectList></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" width="20%">
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><apex:inputText value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
                 <td class="dataCell" >
                    <span><input type="checkbox" value="{!anyWord}"/></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </table>  
         <apex:pageblockButtons >

                <apex:commandButton value="Add Parts" action="{!AddRows}" reRender="addRow"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Tools" action="{!AddRows}" reRender="addRow"/>

            </apex:pageblockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: you can refer my blog for [Insert/Remove rows dynamically in pageblocktable](http://mouryarohit.blogspot.com/2017/04/insertremove-rows-dynamically-in.html)

Comment: Hi Rohit,   I know by using wrapper class we can acheieve this. But I cant use here any as I ahve to use static data and just have to add the row below my table

Comment: tried <apex:outputpanel layout="block"> <- renders as a div ?

Comment: Guys ! found It was mistake I had placed my outputpanel inside the table. Now when I place my outputpanel outside the tale it renders properly . thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found It was mistake I had placed my outputpanel inside the table. Now when I place my outputpanel outside the tale it renders properly